# Set variable number/depth of if elif else statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

Say I had a list `l = [1,2,3,...n]` of indeterminate length, and I wanted to perform some if-elif statements according to the list contents, and the length of the list. So if the length was 3, we would have:

**Updated**

```
p = 2.1

if p < l[0]:
   #quit
elif p >= l[len(n)]:
   #do something and quit
elif p >= l[2] and p<= l[3]:
   #remove l[2], l[1] and l[0] from list
elif p >= l[1] and p<= l[2]:
   #remove l[1] and l[0] 
elif p >= l[0] and p <= l[1]:
   #remove l[0] from list
```

So as I have mentioned, the list is of variable length in each case, it could be 32 for example, there is no upper limit in practice. So how do I create a case (a class, function, or whatever the standard method is) where this logic can be applied to any list or length n?

Some pointers would be nice, I haven't progressed to OOP yet, is this my cue to start?

Comment: So you just want to walk through the list and see where your value fits?

Comment: any cue is good to start OOP. And Python is king in OOP.

Comment: Are you wanting the elif statements to be at a specific increment from the previous one?

Comment: Do you have an infinite number of unrelated `#do something` actions?  I suspect you could use an iterative or recursive solution to do your work if not.

Comment: please describe the logic behind the selection of which/what function must be applied to the elements of the list

Comment: Seems like you want to use a loop.

Comment: @IanAuld and everyone else; I think I might be overthinking this, or I have been too quick in asking the question. I will update the "do something" statements and add more context to give you a better insight.

Comment: If all those "somethings" depends on the list then why not abstract this dependence as a function?

Comment: Your edit to add "if not already removed" makes things more confusing.  Your code only does this removal logic *once*.  Under what circumstances would things "already" have been removed?  From what I see, all your code is doing is removing all leading elements of the list that are less than `p`.  Is that correct?

Comment: @BrenBarn p is a price, which can spike past p=2.1, or even past p=3. If this is the case, a variable stake has to be changed to reflect this movement, hence if the price spikes up, then spikes down, only to come up again, it will trigger p=1, where p=3 has already been hit, which messes up the order logic.

Comment: @BrenBarn I see what you mean, I have reversed the logic.

Comment: @ajsp: I don't understand what you're saying there.  As Pynchia asked, please describe explicitly what the code is trying to accomplish.  If `p` is above 3, it will not trigger after `1`, because 3 is not less than 1.  If you are running this code mutliple times with different values of `p`, you need explain how you're doing that and what you want the result to be.

Comment: Note that only *one* `elif` will be entered.  `elif` means "else if".  If your first `elif` is hit, the remaining `elif`s will not even be checked.  What you say in the comments makes me think you believe execution will "fall through" to a later `elif` if it matches after an earlier one has already matched, but that's not how it works.

Comment: @BrenBarn sorry, I have been too quick in asking the question before thinking it through, now I am all over the place, sorry for any confusion, I will delete the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop all items from the beginning of the list that are lower than `p`.

```
import itertools

p = 2.1
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x < p, l))
```

It gives:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem new to python, I would recommend using simple syntax:

```
l = [1,2,3,4] #must be ordered - if not sorted(l)
p = 2.1

if p < l[0]:
    #quit
l = [elem for elem in l if p < elem]
print l
#prints [3, 4]
```

If the for loop seems too advance for you right now, You can do this instead:

```
l = [1,2,3,4] #must be ordered - if not sorted(l)
p = 2.1

if p < l[0]:
    #quit
    pass
for i in reversed(xrange(len(l))):
    if p > l[i]:
        break

l = l[i+1:]
print l
```

The first method is considered more [pythonic](http://blog.startifact.com/posts/older/what-is-pythonic.html) though.

Comment: @ajsp please accept my answer if it helped you, so others can learn from your question too...